# Print PHP values or words instead of its corresponding incrementing numerical ID's

Tags: php, wordpress

$page_id++ represents page order ID from 0 to 5 inclusive in a wordpress website and increments.

I then include some HTML like so:

```
<div class="page_title <?php echo page_item;?>" id="about"><?php the_title()?></div>
```

the output for the div class is "page_title 0" for the first one.

What I'm wanting to know is if i could replace the number with a word or a class. I've tried creating an array:

```
<?php $page_id = array (0 === 'one', 1 === 'two',2 === 'three',3 ==='four',4 ==='five', 5=== 'six')?>
```

but it just returns: "page_title Array"

EDIT: I've also tried replacing === with => in the Array.

I know I need to read up on my syntax  (or even logic!) here but any help/ explainations or clues even would be appreciated as always.

Comment: Might want to check your $page_id array, as it probably contains `0 => false, 1 => false, 2 => false, 3 => false, 4 => false, 5=> false`. Use `=>` instead of `===`.

Comment: `=>` is the ONLY way to define an array using that notation. doing `1 === 'one'` simply assigns a boolean FALSE into that array slot, since (int)1 is NOT strictly equal to (string)one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually refer to the items in the array, just the array itself.
Are you using a foreach loop to print these out?

```
<?php foreach($page_id as $page_item):?>

   <div class="page_title <?php echo $page_item;?>" id="about"><?php the_title()?></div>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Or alternatively do it manually:

```
 <div class="page_title <?php echo $page_id[0];?>" id="about"><?php the_title()?></div>
```

So you would do that, referencing keys 0 - 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and in fact *should*, be using something besides numbers as class names.  I'm about 78% certain that a class name should contain at least one non-digit character, and should start with a letter.  (That's actually the rule for IDs, it seems.  I'm not finding a hard-set rule for classes, but eh.)

As for how to map numbers to words, you should be looking up the id in your array rather than echoing the whole thing.

```
<?php $page_classes = array(...); ?>
...
<div class="page_title <?= $page_classes[$page_id] ?>" id="about">
  <?php the_title()?>
</div>
```

(Note, if you're doing this in a situation where you expect more than one such div to be printed, you should seriously consider losing the `id` attribute or making it equal to the class name you're printing out or...something.  IDs should be unique.)

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like:

```
<?php

    $pageIDs = array(0 => 'one', 1 => 'two'); // and so on... 
    $page_id = $pageIds[$page_id ];

    // ... Other wordpressy stuff...
```

Essentially, the idea being you grab the value from an array, rather than passing an array as the variable, when you get $page_id in this case, it'll be the string.